# effect all nodes with a shared class

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a page with div's that each have multiple classes.

```
<div class='publication parent20'></div>
<div class='publication parent12 parent42 parent91'></div>
<div class='publication parent20'></div>
<div class='publication parent32 parent23'></div>
```

I need a function that takes a class passed to it as a variable, sets they style of all divs with publication class to none and then sets tags with the specified class.

```
function swap_pub(pub){
  document.getElementById("publication").style.display = "none";
  //set style.display = "block" to all elements with class = pub

}
```

any thoughts on how I would do this.

Comment: does it have to be done in vanilla javascript or have you heard of jQuery?

Comment: how about document.getElementsByClassName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also `querySelectorAll` which is slightly more widely supported than `getElementsByClassName`.

```
function setDisplay(className, display) {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className); 
    var i = items.length;
    while (i--) {
      items[i].style.display = display;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getElementsByClassName()`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

```
var pubs = document.getElementsByClassName('publication'); // a NodeList

for (var i = 0; i < pubs.length; i++) {
    pubs[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

This is how it looks using jQuery:

```
$('.publication').show(); // concise
```

Comment: The result from `getElementsByClassName` is not an array. It is a live `NodeList` which can be tricky since the list will respond when nodes inside it are changed. It also will not have all of the methods arrays do.